How to handle glycan structures for bio-/cheminformatics in Python?
I am currently trying to do some machine learning on biological reaction sequences which include glycans. To represent the substrates and products as vectors I am comparing different fingerprints that I calculate using rdkit. For most compounds on found in KEGG this is not a problem as I can download their structure as .mol files and then parse these with rdkit. For glycans this format is not available and I have so far been unable to find any reliable way to turn these glycans into rdkit mols or any other standard structure format like SMILES. Please let me know how I should handle glycans in a chemical/ bioinformatics setting. Ultimately, I just want to calculate a few different fingerprints (Morgan, MACCSKEYS, etc.) and compare. What I need is a a way to read glycan structure files in Python. I have obtained the glycan structures in KCF, WURCS and IUPAC formats but can't figure out how to handle them in Python for further analysis.

If no one answers here, you may have better luck on bioinformatics.stackexchange.com. Be sure to update your question to include a link to the cross-posted question if you do so, or flag your question to be directly migrated.

It would help to know what you mean by "turn these glycans into rdkit mols", what is the starting glycan molecular data format you are looking at? Is it just some label on KEGG or what? See also here.

I have edited the question to add detail on the formats I have available. Thanks for the advice.

The example glycan Sialyl Lewis x antigen from KEGG has a SMILES entry on its on it's PubChem entry. Could you implement a (probably computationally/time expensive) search for the glycan names in your DB and pull the SMILES from the PubChem pages?

I'd try http://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com @MaximilianPress has a good answer.

It seems like there are a few options, I don't know much about these but they will at least allow you to read structures into format that people use for structural analysis:

https://glypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Quickstart.html
https://github.com/BojarLab/glycowork

For a particular application see here.
